# How to mount external disk with sshfs and show the name in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, mount, open-source

I am using `sshfs` a lot to mount external disks using MacOS 12.3.1. The command I am using is something like

```
sshfs $USER@28.28.28.127:/remote_folder ~/remote -o 'allow_other,gid=10067'
```

and then this remote location is available in my terminal under `remote`. Because I created a folder named `remote` in my home folder.

However, when I use "Finder" to navigate to that remote mounted folder, I see the following instead:

[image]

Finder does not show this folder `remote` as `remote`, but instead as `macFUSE Volume 0 (sshfs)`. This can become extremely annoying if you have more than one folder mounted. Because then you do not know which one to use, as "Finder" decided to rename them.

How can I fix this problem? How can I make Finder to show the folder `remote` with the name `remote`? Not with label `apple`, not `banana`, not `macFUSE Volume 0 (sshfs)`, but `remote`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a volname argument. Have you tried adding

```
-ovolname=remote
```

… when you use ssh to make sftp build a snapshot of the remote filesystem locally on your Mac.

Answer (score -1):

I followed this post:
https://www.itsfullofstars.de/2022/03/mount-a-remote-directory-via-ssh-on-macos-sshfs/

and the -ovolname=remote option that @bmike mentioned worked for me on Apple M2 Pro, Ventura 13.3.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/338094)